# How to Fasten Knn Algorithm for face recognition in real time

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle, face-recognition

I am doing my work on face detection and recognition,  where I want to detect the faces in real time,

but when coming to the point of training it is taking very long time to train the

data  is it possible to reduce the timing of training the data can any one help

me out with this problem

'''

```
def train(train_dir, model_save_path=None, n_neighbors=None, knn_algo='ball_tree', verbose=False):
    
    X = []
    y = []

    # Loop through each person in the training set
    for class_dir in tqdm(os.listdir(train_dir)):

        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(train_dir, class_dir)):
            continue

        # Loop through each training image for the current person
        for img_path in image_files_in_folder(os.path.join(train_dir, class_dir)):
            image = face_recognition.load_image_file(img_path)
            face_bounding_boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

            if len(face_bounding_boxes) != 1:
                # If there are no people (or too many people) in a training image, skip the image.
                if verbose:
                    print("Image {} not suitable for training: {}".format(img_path, "Didn't find a face" if len(face_bounding_boxes) < 1 else "Found more than one face"))
            else:
                # Add face encoding for current image to the training set
                X.append(face_recognition.face_encodings(image, known_face_locations=face_bounding_boxes)[0])
                y.append(class_dir.split('_')[0])

    # Determine how many neighbors to use for weighting in the KNN classifier
    if n_neighbors is None:
        n_neighbors = int(round(math.sqrt(len(X))))
        if verbose:
            print("Chose n_neighbors automatically:", n_neighbors)

    # Create and train the KNN classifier
    knn_clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n_neighbors, algorithm=knn_algo, weights='distance')
    print(knn_clf)
    knn_clf.fit(X, y)

    # Save the trained KNN classifier
    if model_save_path is not None:
        with open(model_save_path, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(knn_clf, f)

    return knn_clf
```

'''

this the final call

'''

```
def trainer():
    # STEP 1: Train the KNN classifier and save it to disk
    # Once the model is trained and saved, you can skip this step next time.
    print("Training KNN classifier...")
    classifier = train("app/facerec/dataset", model_save_path="app/facerec/models/trained_model.clf", n_neighbors=3)
    print("Training complete!")
```

'''

also wants to know is there any possibility instead of rewriting the 'trained_model.clf' file can we update the file instead.

Comment: Are you using Scikit-learn for KNN ?

Comment: Yes @KnowledgeGainer

Comment: Training time usually depends upon the size of your dataset and also, KNN does not use any GPU, so generally it will take time as compared to GPU based frameworks.
Can I know the size of your dataset that you are using to train?

Comment: Actually data set contains of images for particular folder atleast 15 images it is like when number of user gets added no of folders gets increased similarly images

Comment: If i get it right then you mean to say, it will keep on increase as the users will be added and each user will have 15 image of its own, right ?

Comment: yes @KnowledgeGainer

Comment: And are you planning to train it everytime a new user is added ?

Comment: the code i have is training all the data everytime when ever i  am using training option

Comment: I can suggest that, If you want to increase the training speed, you can decrease the dimension of images which you are giving as input for faster processing.

Comment: Thank you i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Training kNN model shouldn't impose high runtime overhead. After all, the straightforward ("exact search") model is lazy. It stores the vectors and performs brute-force search at query (or classification) time.

I speculate the embedding computations dominate your training time.

As mentioned by @johncasey, you might want to use approximated-kNN models (or [similarity search](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/what-is-similarity-search/) engines). There are many open-source similarity search libraries. Yet, if you need a production-ready, robust, real-time, efficient solution, then you should check out [pinecone.io](https://www.pinecone.io/docs/). (Disclaimer, I work for Pinecone.)

Answer (score 0):

k-nn algorithm has a O(n) time complexity. I recommend you to use approximate nearest neighbor (a-nn) algorithm. Its time complexity is too low. For example, Google image search is based on this algorithm.

Spotify annoy, Facebook faiss, nmslib are a-nn libraries.